# What is the maximum number of view controllers that can be part of a UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

Please answer this question.

I know that it is pretty trivial, but I do not possess sufficient knowledge to be able to answer it myself, that is why I am asking the readers of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum amount of Tabs before a "more" button appears is 4, but you can essentially have as many as you want as long you have enough memory.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> The tab bar has limited space for displaying your custom items. If you add six or more custom view controllers to a tab bar controller, the tab bar controller displays only the first four items plus the standard More item on the tab bar. Tapping the More item brings up a standard interface for selecting the remaining items.

Comment: Thanks, such a simple answer.

Comment: The maximum number of Tabs before a "more" tab appears is 5.  "More..." doesn't appear until you have at least 6 view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the maximum number of `tabBar` items before to show tap more it is possible using KVC

```
[self.tabBar setValue:@(numberOfMaxToShowTabMore) forKey:@"customMaxItems"];
```

And this code you must insert before add controllers in `tabBar`